# Do we know of any vitamin or mineral deficiencies that cause an increase in appetite?

Tags: nutrition, minerals, zinc, loss-of-appetite, appetite

I know that people who lack Zinc tend to have **less** appetite. In contrast: have any vitamin or mineral deficiencies that cause an increase in appetite been found in the seemingly-objective scientific research?

Comment: Beware of supplement-related "information" you find on the web. A lot of that information is spurious anecdotes and nonsense designed to get you to buy the supplement.